# Difficulty using Put on a FloatBuffer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm removing some native C code from an Android app which used a memcpy to copy an array of floats into a FloatBuffer (because an old device I had was very slow at this).

My current code looks like this:

```
mfVertexBuffer.position(0);
mfColourBuffer.position(0);
mfSizeBuffer.position(0);
mfVertexBuffer.put(fvertices, 0, nCount*2);
mfColourBuffer.put(fcolours, 0, nCount*4);
mfSizeBuffer.put(fsizes, 0, nCount);
```

I've looked at the state of mfVertexBuffer and it looks like it's behaving; .position gets incremented sensibly, and the contents of the underlying buffer seem sensible.  However, nothing is being rendered onscreen (by a later process).

I rewrote the above - changing nothing else in my app whatsoever - to the following:

```
int vs=0;
int vd=0;
int cs=0;
int cd=0;
int ss=0;
int sd=0;
for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++) {
   mfVertexBuffer.put(vd++, fvertices[vs++]);
   mfVertexBuffer.put(vd++, fvertices[vs++]);
   mfColourBuffer.put(cd++, fcolours[cs++]);
   mfColourBuffer.put(cd++, fcolours[cs++]);
   mfColourBuffer.put(cd++, fcolours[cs++]);
   mfColourBuffer.put(cd++, fcolours[cs++]);
   mfSizeBuffer.put(sd++, fsizes[ss++]);
}
```

And it works perfectly.  I don't understand this at all. How do the two pieces of code differ?

The FloatBuffers are set up like this:

```
mfVertexBuffer = miscHelpers.getFloatBuffer(4 * NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES * 2);
mfColourBuffer = miscHelpers.getFloatBuffer(4 * NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES * 4);
mfSizeBuffer = miscHelpers.getFloatBuffer(4 * NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES);

public static FloatBuffer getFloatBuffer(int size) {
   FloatBuffer fbRet;
   ByteBuffer myBB = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
   myBB.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
   fbRet = myBB.asFloatBuffer();
   return fbRet;
}
```

fvertices etc are simple arrays of floats, the values of which do not change.

count is the number of particles to plot this round.

NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES is a compile time limit on the maximum number of particles which can be created, and is always more than or equal to count, so the first (non-working) code is doing more work, but behaves the same if I set NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES to the same value as count.

I'm using OpenGL 1.1, Android API 17 on a Galaxy S3 running 4.2.2 (Cyanogenmod 10.1.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a buffer to an OpenGL function, it will start reading at the current position.

The first form of `put()` you are using, where you pass in the whole array at once, increases the position by the number of floats written. The second form with the `put(int index, float f)` signature does not update the position, according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#put%28int,%20float%29).

When using the first variation, you need to reset the position to the start after filling the buffer. There are a few calls you can choose from to do this:

```
buffer.position(0);
buffer.rewind();
buffer.flip();
```

`flip()` is the one most people seem to use, but the other options will work as well in your use case.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm already doing (ie in the first line of my code)?

Comment: Well, yes, you're setting the position there. But then it gets updated by the `put()` calls. You need to reset the position to 0 **after** making the `put()` calls.

Comment: You're right. I was only thinking about my writes into the buffer; I didn't appreciate that OpenGL uses the position as it reads it whilst rendering.  Many thanks!